# Pressed button should be on stay on the background,but this color disappears

Tags: python, tkinter

is in tkinter any option, if i click on a button, the button color stays on the activebackground, i do my things on the appearing frame, and if i click next button, the color on the button (pressed before) dissappear and the next button gets the nnew color. i tried different `bind`functions. but `<Enter>`, `<Leave>` and `<Button-1>`, dont give me this effect. And is there any option, to combine it about two frames? I have in one fram icons and in the other texts (icons and text are buttons)

for example: i click (this is with `activebackground`)
[image]

@JacksonPro

```
        self.home_btn = Button(self.navi_frame, bg="#181b20", image=home, bd=0, activebackground="#d06276")
        self.home_btn.place(x=0, y=110, width=80, height=48)
        self.home_btn.bind("<Enter>", self.home_moE)
        self.home_btn.bind("<Leave>", self.home_moL)
```

```
    def home_moE(self, event):
        self.home_label["bg"] = "#d06276"
        self.home_btn["bg"] = "#d06276"
```

but i want that this color stays, since i press another button.

Comment: Can you provide [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: If you would do `button.bind('<Button-1>', change_button_bg)` you should be fine. Dont you?

Comment: @JacksonPro i added the code on top. and @Atlas435 i tried it with `<Button-1>` but the color  dissapears

Comment: you don't need `Enter` and `Leave` event. You could just use `Button(command=self.home_moE)`

Comment: yes but i want this mouseover. or doesn't it works together? so i want to combine mouseover and the pressed button. but if i leave this area, the color disappear. and if I delete bind. `<Leave>` i have all buttons in this color

Comment: please provide [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and explain yourself better.